Solana, Anchor programs Release Profile opt
was curious around profile optimisations for solana programs, one compilation option I did not find any programs atleast the ones I came across was the

[profile.release]
strip='debug-info'

which removes the debug info reducing binary size which would lower deployment costs, was curious if there is any downside due to which programs dont use this optimisation ?

All programs are stripped automatically when running the cargo build-sbf command:
            let output = spawn(
                &config.sbf_sdk.join("scripts").join("strip.sh"),
                [&program_unstripped_so, &program_so],
                config.generate_child_script_on_failure,
            );

This calls ~/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin/sdk/sbf/scripts/strip.sh, which does:
"$sbf_sdk"/dependencies/platform-tools/llvm/bin/llvm-objcopy --strip-all "$so" "$so_stripped"

Source code at https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/758477331271d2ba79d392e36c71e4e98f06761e/sdk/cargo-build-sbf/src/main.rs#L788-L792
As you noticed, it would be very bad if programs weren't stripped!
